# Is it bad math style to use one letter for indexing two objects?

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

Is $$\sum_{i\in I_1} a_i + \sum_{i \in I_2} b_i$$ or $$\prod_{i\in I_1} a_i \cdot \prod_{i \in I_2} b_i$$ confusing or bad math?
Should I rather use $j$ for indexing the $b$'s?

Comment: I think it's better to use different summation indices, just to avoid error or confusion but it's clear what you mean in each case.

Comment: It's perfectly fine, and not confusing to anyone who understands the notation. Why would you change the index? What if you had four sums? Or ten? Or twenty-seven?

Comment: I think the product could be very confusing if $I_1$ and $I_2$ have different cardinalities. The sum is probably fine, unless you might want to combine them into one sum later on, in which case the cardinality problem crops up again. That sum might not be very well-defined.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Why are different cardinalities any more problematic with the product? In each case, we're adding or multiplying $|I_1|+|I_2|$ objects.

Comment: @J.G. It's more of an issue if you want to combine into one product. Then it's not clear what the limits of the summation should be.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Again, the combining option when $|I_1|=|I_2|$ doesn't depend on whether we're summing or multiplying.